# need advice on USB bootable Format tools

Tags: boot, usb, formatting

I need some tool to use with my work incoming weeks   i have to format like hundreds of PCs

i have  64 mb USBdrive  i need to put it too good use in this work.so tool have to be below 64 mb

**As far as i know about tool** and i have try it out

DBAN  ----- too extreme, take a lot of time

Gparted ---- too large  for 64 mb

Damn small linux  ------ it's too complicate and waste time on loading

Fdisk ----- this one is okay but need advice on modify it

**i would like to have program that(in dos boot screen like MSDOS boot)**

-plug USBdrive then boot up via usb

-have choice for you atleast 2 choice 
----E.G. Choose to Format HDD and Exit

**If this kind of similar tool** is not exist can you suggest me of how to build it or anyone have this kind of lookalike program please inform me

This is just my curiosity and want to find out that is it possible or not

Comment: How thorough this formating should be?

Comment: just like using Window install DVD format is fine i think :)

Comment: I would use `FreeDOS`, it's small fast and simple as `format.exe`.

Comment: i install freedos on my USB make bootable

then  i try fdisk   it said " there are no fdisk command"

Comment: Dos uses `diskpart` it's similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Partition wizard boot disc

Download partition wizard bootable CD image file from this [link](http://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-wizard-bootable-cd.html)

Download `universal USB installer` and make a [bootable USB](http://www.sevenforums.com/software/217114-how-do-i-boot-partition-wizard-bootable-cd-my-usb.html) from the downloaded image file

Boot to partition wizard

Select screen size

Then you will be able to manage your partition from the partition wizard console.

Answer (score 1):

1 - DISKPART and hit enter, you get the message.

2 - LIST DISK command and write down the Disk number.

3 - List of commands to type

SELECT DISK 1 (whatever your USB disk nº is)

CLEAN

CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY

SELECT PARTITION 1

ACTIVE

FORMAT FS=NTFS

ASSIGN

EXIT

4 - Insert your Windows CD/DVD in your DVD-ROM (we asume it is letter D),
cd to the boot directory in the CD/DVD

5 - Type: BOOTSECT.EXE /NT60 E: (being E your USB stick drive letter)

6 - Copy the whole installation CD/DVD contents to the flash drive.

(Original article by Tim Fisher at about.com, this is an extract from my notes)

Comment: thank i want to up for you but right now my reputation too low